# Cmake include header only library with -I option

Tags: c++, cmake, symbolic-math

I have a header only library that is contained in a "headers/" directory in the main project. When compiling from terminal I include it with `#include "symbolicc++.h"`, but I need to pass the option `-I "headers/"` when compiling with g++. How can I include this in a Cmake project? (And also, in general how can I pass other option such as `-pthread` to Cmake?

Comment: Adding the include directory in the `CMakeLists.txt` file and having an appropriate `#include "symbolicc++.h"` in the client code should be sufficient, so what's your actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding include directories in CMake is done by using the **`target_include_directories`** directive.

Use it this way (in your `CMakeLists.txt`):

```
target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC ${SOME_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

**Some more info:** [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html)